# Generate/edit source file for transifex

Tags: translation, transifex

i want to use transifex for my open source project (so transifex is also free to use) but compared to https://localise.biz/free/poeditor its not as easy to use. What im trying to do is to generate or at least update a source file from within transifex without having to download the translation file and reupload it again to update the source file

one can generate and update at transifex, but thats something different, as i learnt. its not supposed to be used for simple strings like 'Hello world'

if there is no way to do that online for some reason...well i suppose there would be a reason, right? but even that would be good to know anyway.

what i did now was to generate a po file with localise.biz since i had no clue what it should look like and imported it to transifex. there is a tool called POedit, but that wasnt of much help either..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way Transifex works is that you upload your source file, and all translation files are managed by the system automatically. You can [update the source file](https://docs.transifex.com/projects/updating-content#manually-updating-source-files) many times (without interfering with the translation files).

Think about it this way. You already have some code which has "Hello, world!" coded. You use your programming language's standard i18n library to mark that phrase and export it into a source language file (eg. `en.po`). You upload this in Transifex, choose your languages, and you now have an English file, a French and an Italian one. If your source file changes (eg. because you added a phrase in your code and it now has, say, 11 phrases), you re-upload your source file to Transifex, and you'll now have all files (en, fr, it) with 11 phrases.

You can't generate or edit, really, a source file in Transifex. It relies on you having one already.

Comment: thanks, i now understood the idea of transifex and co better. So i first implement the  strings in my code let the (in my case) angular cli generate the source file and then upload it to transifex.....

Comment: That's correct, yes. You can use the [Transifex Client](https://docs.transifex.com/client/introduction) to easily upload your files in Transifex as well.